# Greenshot and CapsLock/NumLock indicator

Tags: windows, numlock, greenshot

Whenever I press the CapsLock or NumLock keys, I get a visual indicator:

[image: CapsLock indicator]

It usually doesn't bother me, but when I try to use Greenshot and the PrintScreen or ALT+PrintScreen keyboard shortcuts, the NumLock indicator pops up and gets included in the screenshot.

It appears as though Greenshot is toggling NumLock on and off when pressing PrintScreen, because the indicator appears after the screenshot has been taken.

- If NumLock is on, I see the NumLock-off indicator, then the NumLock-on indicator
- If NumLock is off, then I first see the NumLock-on indicator, then the NumLock-off

This only happens when Greenshot is running; otherwise PrintScreen and ALT+PrintScreen have no additional artifacts.

I have a Lenovo Y730 running Windows 10, and I've seen this behavior since I first got the laptop.

Has anyone seen this indicator or this behavior? How can I turn it off?

This issue has been previously reported at the [Greenshot JIRA](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/BUG-2233).

Comment: I think this could be fixed with a Setting in the ease of accessibility that I don't remember

Comment: @SaaranshGarg There are settings for sounds when NumLock / CapsLock is pressed, but I didn't see anything about a visual indicator.

Comment: That's because the indicator comes from your laptop's Lenovo drivers, not from Windows itself.

Comment: @user1686 Perhaps, but then why does PrintScreen trigger a NumLock toggle, and that only when Greenshot is running? And the question still remains: how do I turn it off?

Comment: Have you tried with one of the latest unstable releases, as Robin has suggested in the comments of the JIRA ticket?